# Splunk search if host is inactive for more than 5 minutes

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have two specific messages in splunk data that I'm searching for per user.

- active
- inactive
  Anyone know how I can search in splunk for a user that is inactive for more than 5 minutes.
  I already have the search where it finds the inactive and active messages and a timestamp for each.
  What I want to do is only return results if the time between those 2 messages was more than 5 minutes per user.

Example:

```
index="document" (message="inactive" OR message="active")
```

Not sure how to work out the time between those two messages based on the timestamp per user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.

````
index="document" (message="inactive" OR message="active")
```Create a new field called "duration" that the difference between the last value of _time and the current value```
| streamstats window=2 range(_time) as duration by user
```Show only the active users with duration greater than 5 minutes (300 seconds)```
| where (message="inactive" AND duration>300)
````

Comment: Thank you RichG what exactly does streamstats window=2 do ?

Comment: Does it matter the order of the (message="inactive" OR message="active") as the query doesn't seem to work for me after the 5 minutes.

Comment: The comment above the command explains what it does.
The order within the OR clause is not significant.
What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work after the 5 minutes"?  If you're getting no results then either no user has been inactive for 5 minutes or no data was found in the index.

Comment: Right I see your comment but I'm asking what does window=2 do ? I've never used that before. why 2 ?

Comment: `window=2` means to use the current event and 1 previous event (total of 2) in the stats calculation.